# PyCharm move Python function to module

Tags: python, refactoring, pycharm

Is there an easy way in PyCharm (Community Edition) to update references to a function that has moved from current file.py to some module?

Originally

```
main.py:

def foo():

def bar():
   return foo()

def baz():
   return foo()
```

Now

```
main.py
import MyFunc

def bar():
  return MyFunc.foo()

def baz():
  return MyFunc.foo()

MyFunc.py

def foo():
```

This all works well, but I'm in the process of refactoring and going through the entire code manually fixing references to "foo()" is a bit of a pain. Code->Inspect Code helps greatly but is there a way to "Refactor move function to module"?

Comment: Why don't you just replace it?

Answer (score 1):

Refactor | Move... does this for you. Note that it moves the function and updates the references; you can't invoke it *after* the function has been moved.